# Open Firefox web console be default when it start?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console

I need to use Firefox web console a lot and I want every time I open Firefox, the Web Console panel will display automatically. Currently I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to open it.

Is there any way to config the Firefox browser to make it work as I want? I prefer the native way (ie. changing configuration) rather than having install another plugins. I only need the webconsole, don't need the whole toolbox like firebug or something like that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a Debian derived Linux. Just installed Firefox Quantum (Firefox 57).

```
$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 57.0
```

The --devtools option seems to bring up Firefox with a Web console visible.

```
$ firefox --devtools
```

Comment: Yeah this works to open initially, but it doesn't open automatically with any new tab/window. Shame.